# Consultas de relaciones ORM Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estoy trabajando en una tienda online en donde cada negocio tiene una pagina donde se muestra sus productos, mediante las relaciones eloquent he podido mostrar las categorias de cada usuario en su respectiva pagina pero al tratar de ver las subcategorias de cada categoria,no he podido hacer que se muestren en su respectiva pagina.

Mi pregunta es como puedo mandar a llamar a las subcategorias correspondientes a cada categoria con eloquent, teniendo en cuenta que en subcategoria no tengo una FK de la tabla users.

[image: Filtrar subcategorias de categorias]

Este es Mi controlador

```
 public function user(Request $request,$name)
 {  
$product = User::with(['productos' => function ($query) {
$query->where('nuevo', '=', '1')->take(8);}])->where('name', $name)->get();

$user = User::with(['productos' => function ($query) {
$query->where('condicioon','=','0')->paginate(7);}],'categorias')
->where('name', $name)
->get();
    return view("store.user",compact('user','product'));

}
```

Mis modelo User

```
  public function categorias()
{
    return $this->hasMany('laravel\Categoria');
}

   public function productos()
{
    return $this->hasMany('laravel\Producto');
}
```

Habia intentado verlas de esta forma pero tampoco he conseguido nada

```
public function subcategorias()
{ return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'laravel\Categoria',
        'laravel\Subcategoria',
        'id', // Foreign key on categorias table...
        'idCategoria', // Foreign key on subcategoria table...
        'id', // Local key on users table...
        'idCategoria' // Local key on categorias table...
    );}









introducir el código aquí
<div class="col-sm-3">{{--Panel izquierdo--}}
            <div class="left-sidebar">
                <h2>Categorias</h2>
                <div class="panel-group category-products" id="accordian">{{--Categorias--}}
                    @foreach($user  as $us)
                    @foreach($us->categorias as $cat)
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">

                                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordian" href="#{{camel_case($cat->nombre)}}">
                                            <span class="badge pull-right"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
                                            {{$cat->nombre}}
                                        </a>

                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id="{{camel_case($cat->nombre)}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">

                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <ul>

                                        <li><a href="">aqui van las subcategorias</a></li>

                                     </ul>
                                 </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                    @endforeach
                    @endforeach
                </div>{{--./Categorias--}}


            </div> 
          <div class="search-product pos-relative bo4 of-hidden">
          <input class="s-text7 size6 p-l-23 p-r-50" type="text" name="search-product" placeholder="Search Products...">

          <button class="flex-c-m size5 ab-r-m color2 color0-hov trans-0-4">
            <i class="fs-12 fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
        </div>{{--./Panel izquierdo--}}
```

Comment: Desde una categoría debes de acceder a sus subcategorias. Debes de definir correctamente esta relación

foreach($user->categories as $category){
    $category->subcategories;
}

Comment: No me queda muy claro el problema, si ya tienes el modelo Subcategoria definido, ¿por qué no puedes mostrar las subcategorías?

Comment: Si las puedo mostrar pero se muestran todas las subcategorias de la base de datos y no las subcategorias de cada usuario

Comment: Muéstranos como defines las relaciones entre los modelos Categoria y SubCategoria.

Comment: mi modelo categoria se encuentra asi                
      public function subcategorias()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('laravel\Subcategoria','idCategoria','user_id');
    }

Comment: mi modelo subcategoria se encuentra asi                                                        public function productos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('laravel\Producto','idCategoria','idSubcategoria');
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estos son los datos que considero relevantes de lo que has pasado en la pregunta y comentarios:

Relaciones **Modelo `User`**

```
public function categorias()
{
    return $this->hasMany('laravel\Categoria');
}
```

Relaciones **Modelo `Categoria`**

```
public function subcategorias() 
{ 
    return $this->hasMany('laravel\Subcategoria','idCategoria','user_id'); 
}
```

---

Y aquí vienen algunos cambios, los comenté en el código:

**Controlador**

```
public function user(Request $request,$name)
{  
    $products = ... // sin cambios, solo lo pasé a plural porque es una colección

    $users = User::with([ // también lo pasé a plural por el mismo motivo
                        'productos' => function ($query) {
                            $query->where('condicioon','=','0')->paginate(7);
                        },
                        'categorias' => function ($query) { // <- este es el cambio que hice respecto a tu query!!!
                            $query->with('subcategorias');
                        },
                ])
                ->where('name', $name)
                ->get();

    return view("store.user",compact('users','products')); // ahora son en plural!! tendrás que checkar en la vista para que no te dé un error con las variable, sobre todo productos
}
```

Vista

```
@foreach($users  as $user)
    @foreach($user->categorias as $categoria)
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordian" href="#{{ camel_case($categoria->nombre) }}">
                    <span class="badge pull-right"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
                    {{ $categoria->nombre }}
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="{{ camel_case($categoria->nombre) }}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul>
                @foreach($categoria->subcategorias as $subcategoria)
                    <li><a href="">{{ $subcategoria->nombre }}</a></li> // le puse ->nombre, porque no sé que campos tiene
                @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: uchisimas gracias esto es lo que necesitaba

Comment: ok, si responde a tu pregunta puedes marcarla como [aceptada, o darle un voto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si te ha servido de ayuda ;)